# Adding Rasters with multiple Field Values using Map Algebra in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, fields-attributes, map-algebra

Embarrassed that I haven't looked at this for some time (can't quite get the syntax down). (ArcGIS 10.2, Win7x64).

Within Map Algebra (Raster Calculator)
Trying to add the cell values of 3 rasters, each raster has multiple fields. Trying to add:
SumRaster = (Raster1, Field X)+ (Raster2, FieldY)+ (Raster3, FieldZ).

Can get to run (using primary VALUE field from each), want to specify FIELD value to SUM.

Alternately would be OK to export each Raster, setting my desired VALUE from this specified Field (and don't remember how to do this in 10.2).

Any help with Syntax would be great.

Comment: I'd export them to grids and use cell statistics. Lookup is very slow on big rasters

Comment: They actually are grids and fortunately, reasonably small. So very happy that the LOOKUP function worked (plus, it's great to know about).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Lookup](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sn000000) function:

```
Lookup("Raster1", "FieldX") + Lookup("Raster2", "FieldY") + Lookup("Raster3", "FieldZ")
```

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks! (I've never actually used that, so this'll be most useful).... Appreciate your help.

Comment: Done.... and thanks again; this was a huge help... and totally did it for me.

Comment: The best way to say thanks to @Luke is by clicking the green accept check mark next to his answer which says that helped you and gives him 15 pts bonus.